# com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: sql-server-2005, java-8, jdbc-odbc

I has db in MS SQL Server 2005

I has java project write on **java 8**. My project is on **Windows 7 Professional's machine (64 bit)**.

I use this jar: `sqljdbc4.jar` to connect to **MS SQL Server 2005**.

But when I start my app I get error:

```
 [java] log4j: setFile ended
 [java] log4j: Appender [File] to be rolled at midnight.
 [java] log4j: Adding appender named [File] to category [root].
 [java] [25.05.2019 15:11:44.979] com.myproject.common.LNFSetter.setLNF(LNFSetter.java:60) TRACE:
 [java]     lookAndFeelName=Windows
 [java]     lookAndFeelClassName=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 [java]     at com.myproject.db.DBManagerContext.initConnection(DBManagerContext.java:69)
 [java]     at com.myproject.db.DBManagerContext.initialize(DBManagerContext.java:94)
 [java]     at com.myproject.db.DBManagerContext.<init>(DBManagerContext.java:102)
 [java]     at com.myproject.db.DBManagerContext.getInstance(DBManagerContext.java:115)
 [java]     at com.myproject.common.SystemOptions.getDBManagerContext(SystemOptions.java:382)
 [java]     at com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManager.initialize(M2DocumentManager.java:42)
 [java]     at com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManager.<init>(M2DocumentManager.java:60)
 [java]     at com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManager.getInstance(M2DocumentManager.java:35)
 [java]     at com.myproject.views.ca.scroller.AccountsScroller.init(AccountsScroller.java:182)
 [java]     at com.myproject.views.ca.scroller.AccountsScroller.<init>(AccountsScroller.java:160)
 [java]     at com.myproject.views.ca.MainScreenView.<init>(MainScreenView.java:103)
 [java]     at com.myproject.Main.<init>(Main.java:42)
 [java]     at com.myproject.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Here my app's snippet:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;
    private void initConnection(String suffixURL) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            String driverName = UserOptions.getOptionsDBDriverName();
            Class.forName(driverName); // ERROR IN THIS LINE
            String url = null;
            String databaseType = UserOptions.getOptionsDBURLType();
            String host = UserOptions.getOptionsDBURLHost();
            String port = UserOptions.getOptionsDBURLPort();
            String databaseName = UserOptions.getOptionsDBURLName();
            if (suffixURL == null) {
                url = UserOptions.getOptionsAdditionalDBURL(databaseType, host, port, databaseName);
            } else {
                url = suffixURL;
            }
                String userName = UserOptions.getOptionsDBUserName();
            String password = UserOptions.getOptionsDBPassword();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        }
```

Error in this line:

```
Class.forName(driverName); // ERROR IN THIS LINE
```

comment:

```
driver name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

P.S. I can't upgrade to **jdk 9**. I can use only **jdk 8**

Comment: `55` in `.class` files means `java-11` compilation... and these types of questions have been asked _numerous_ times around here

Comment: @Eugene I can't upgrade to jdk 9. I can use only java 8

Comment: I said `java-11` not 9... But anyway get a jar that was compiled with java-8

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the answer for newcomers via search engines.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver **has been compiled by a
> more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)**,

means that the `.jar` file compiled with a newer version of Java than you have on your computer.

> **this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0**

means that your computer has a lower level of Java as you can see below table. What you should this is to upgrade your Java or choose appropriate version of Mssql java files from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc).

```
Java SE 18  62  003e
Java SE 17  61  003d
Java SE 16  60  003c
Java SE 15  59  003b
Java SE 14  58  003a
Java SE 13  57  0039
Java SE 12  56  0038
Java SE 11  55  0037
Java SE 10  54  0036
Java SE 9   53  0035
Java SE 8   52  0034
Java SE 7   51  0033
Java SE 6   50  0032
Java SE 5   49  0031
JDK 1.4     48  0030
JDK 1.3     47  002f
JDK 1.2     46  002e
JDK 1.1     45  002d
```

After I carry out the in question way, I get the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, simply lower the version of jar in your dependency.
Try adding this to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```