# How to solve error when creating WSO2 EI Data Source

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm getting blow error when creating a new ms sql type data source in wso2 EI 6.6 any clue?

com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that from the error that the mssql driver has complied with a newer version of java. You may need to use an earlier version of the driver-jar which is compatible with the existing java version of your VM.

[1]-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304767/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent